# NUnit: Fail Test when OneTimeTearDown fails

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0, pact

**Abstract goal**: I’m working with NUnit (3.9.0 at the moment). Some work to finish the tests is done in the OneTimeTearDown method. When this work fails, I need an indication, i.e. one or more tests should fail.

**Background**: I’m implementing PACT Tests using NUnit as the Unit Test framework. On the consumer, after all tests are run, I have to generate and upload the PACT file to the PACT broker. If this fails, e.g. when the pact broker is down, I need to have an indication; i.e. one or all tests should fail.

**Question**: Is this possible using NUnit? If so: How? Or would there be a better approach to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 2):

You could call the same assert methods from your `OneTimeTearDown` method as you call from the tests. Here is example that fails test run from teardown method:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeClassTests
{
    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        Assert.Fail("Failed to upload file to the PACT broker");
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

Here is execution result in ReSharper UT runner:

[image]

Another option to fail test run from teardown method is to throw exception.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t reproduce your solution. Using NUnit 3.9.0, Visual Studio 2015 & ReSharper 10.0.2. Neither in the ReSharper UnitTest Runner, nor in the Visual Studio Test Explorer I can get a hint that something went wrong. I only see it in the Test-Text-Output. But this is very unhandy, I doubt the developers would see this hint. And we would need to hack something on the build servers. I also can’t find any flag to set in NUnit to reproduce your solution. Or any setting in ReSharper.

Comment: It works for me using NUnit 3.9.0, Visual Studio 2015 and ReSharper 2016.1.1. So probably this feature was introduced in some version of ReSharper UT Runner after 10.0.2.

Comment: With an updated ReSharper Version it works as you described. Whether I could convince all our developers to even install ReSharper is another question ;) And this solution only covers the development machines. On our build servers the builds are still green. Therefor I would prefer to have a way where an actual TestCase fails. This would cover all scenarios. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only you can use ReSharper, the output is clearly visible.but you also can use `output` or Nunit 2.X，Please see the details[Nunit3 console doesn't show test output continuously](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1139)